# How to iterate through sorted iterable in Python

Tags: python

Let's say S is an iterable where each subelement is not necessarily sorted. Normally I might do

```
for element in S:
    element=sorted(element)
    ...
```

Is there a way to do something like

```
for sorted(element) in S:
    ...
```

Comment: So... what is your question?

Comment: Have you tried your own code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a genexp, but your original code is already good enough:

```
for element in (sorted(x) for x in S):
   # do things
```

Another approach that uses less code is `map`:

```
for element in map(sorted, S):
    # or itertools.imap on Python2.x if you need iterators...
```

Comment: I think this is the best option, though the explicit version in the question is maybe even more clear. The only suggesetion I'd have is to avoid confusion by not reusing the same name `element` in the different parts of the statement.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to return a list, you could do a list comprehension

```
[sorted(element) for element in S]
```